# Using $ (dollar sign) in sphinx search

Tags: c#, sphinx

I'm trying to set up fulltext search using sphinx (v2.3.2-beta) for my music-related website.

When a user searchs for 'kesha', he must also find 'Ke$ha'.
In order to do this, I added this to my charset_table:

```
U+0024->s, U+FF04->s, U+FE69->s
```

After that, 'kesha' returns results for 'Ke$ha'.
However, when I search for 'ke$ha', i get no results.

I'm currently using SphinxQL in C#, and I'm manually escaping the $-sign.

```
    private string EscapeQuery(string query)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder(query);
        builder.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
        builder.Replace("-", "\\-");
        builder.Replace("+", "\\+");
        builder.Replace("$", "\\$");
        builder.Replace("!", "\\!");
        builder.Replace("@", "\\@");
        builder.Replace("~", "\\~");
        builder.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
        builder.Replace("/", "\\/");
        builder.Replace("(", "\\(");
        builder.Replace(")", "\\)");
        builder.Replace("*", "\\*");
        builder.Replace("<", "\\<");
        builder.Replace(">", "\\>");
        builder.Replace("=", "\\=");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

In the query log i'm seeing the following, so I think my query is escaped correctly:

```
SELECT artistid, artistname FROM artists WHERE MATCH('^ke\\$ha*') GROUP BY artistid LIMIT 0,2 OPTION ranker=sph04;
/* Fri Feb 10 18:21:37.764 2017 conn 44 real 0.000 wall 0.000 found 0 */
```

However, i'm not getting any results, while I think i should also be getting 'Ke$ha' as a result.

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I have uploaded my config (some indexes removed) [here](http://pastebin.com/M2XRVQpM)

Comment: I have also tried with version 2.2.11, but I'm getting the same results there.
I have also tried using the default mysql client to connect to sphinx, and [this are the results](http://pastebin.com/n09YF91k)

Comment: Using a more simple charset_table gives the same results:
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, ?, !, U+0024->s, U+FF04->s, U+FE69->s, U+00D8->o

Comment: I reported this as a bug
http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=2611